# Not able to install postgresql-plperl-8.4 on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Tags: postgresql-8.4, ubuntu-14.04, plperl

I have recently had a problem installing postgresql-plperl-8.4 on the new Ubuntu 14.04 distribution. When I tried to install it, it gave me this error:

```
postgresql-plperl-8.4 depends on libperl5.10 (>= 5.10.1); 
however: Package libperl5.10 is not installed.
```

Using *dpkg* to check the depency also gives:

> Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libperl5.10 (>= 5.10.1), postgresql-8.4 (= 8.4.21-1.pgdg10.4+1), perl

Fine, then I checked what version of libperl is installed on 14.04 using *dpkg* by running:

> dpkg --search libperl

Then I got results shown below:

```
libperl5.18: /usr/share/doc/libperl5.18
libperl5.18: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libperl5.18
```

which clearly suggests that I have libperl installed with a version that satisfies the need for postgresql-plperl-8.4 and yet it is giving me errors. Can anyone help?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/457726/failure-to-install-postgresql-plperl-8-4-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Out of interest, why would you install plperl for PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 ? Surely it should come with PostgreSQL 9.2 or 9.3...

Comment: @CraigRinger The server that is running 8.4 needs to be upgraded. I'm trying out 14.04 with psql8.4 db because of compatibility issues with other servers running 8.4.

Comment: Where are the 8.4 packages from, then? 8.4 isn't included in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @CraigRinger I obtained it from pkgs.org